Cambiar status automáticamente a 1 o 0 con php y mysql
No puedo cambiar el status a 1 o 0 si el inventario está ocupado o libre;
al darle en editar quiero que se cambie a 1 y cuando guarde el inventario que se cambie a 0.
Aquí es donde quiero enviar el cambio de status al dar click en editar
 $this->data['inventory1'] = $this->inventory_model->getInventoryByID($id);
    if ($this->data['inventory1']->cursostatus == 0){
        $this->db->update( array('cursostatus' => 1), 1);
    }   

Aquí donde hago el update es donde no me cambia el status
$this->data['inventory1'] = $this->inventory_model->getInventoryByID($id);
    if ($this->data['inventory1']->cursostatus == 1){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('Inventario ocupado favor de esperar a que terminen'));
        redirect('inventory');
    }   

La condicional si pongo manual en en mysql 1 y doy click en editar sí funciona.
Mi código está así
 function edit($id = NULL) { 
    $group = $this->site->getUserGroup($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

    if ( !$group->inv_modificar) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('access_denied'));
        redirect('pos');
    }
    if ($this->input->get('id')) {
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
    }
   
    $this->data['inventory1'] = $this->inventory_model->getInventoryByID($id);
    if ($this->data['inventory1']->received == 1){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('access_denied_adjustment'));
    }             
                
  $this->data['inventory1'] = $this->inventory_model->getInventoryByID($id);
    if ($this->data['inventory1']->cursostatus == 0){
        $this->db->update( array('cursostatus' => 1), 1);
    }       
   
    
     $this->data['inventory1'] = $this->inventory_model->getInventoryByID($id);
    if ($this->data['inventory1']->cursostatus == 1){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('Inventario ocupado favor de esperar a que terminen'));
        redirect('inventory');
    }   


Saludos, por favor explica ¿cuál es el problema que tienes?, ¿no funciona? ¿te muestra algún error?, recuerda que siempre puedes editar tu pregunta. ;)

hola. no me muestra ningun error, solo que no me cambia el status de 0 a 1 en mi base de datos al dar click en editar, voy agregar un poco mas de codigo para explicarlo mejor.

El UPDATE que tratas de hacer está mal formulado. Debería haberte dado un error en los logs aunque sea. Falta la tabla y posiblemente un WHERE para saber que quieres actualizar.
$this->db->where('id', $id); //De necesitar un WHERE, debería verse algo así.
$this->db->update('inventory', array('cursostatus' => 1)); //Acá faltaba la tabla que quieres actualizar.
$this->data['inventory1'] = $this->inventory_model->getInventoryByID($id); //Recargar datos

Luego, vemos que la función inicia con $id = NULL, pero en ningún lado realizas la validación de NULL
//La asignación de ID ya estaba correcta
if ($this->input->get('id')) {
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
}

//Pero, agregamos que $id no sea nulo
if (!$id) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('invalid_inventory_id')); //Mensaje de error
    redirect('inventory'); //Redireccionamos
    exit; //Detenemos el resto del script
}

Vale remarcar que luego de una redirección, debes realizar un exit; para detener la ejecución del código.
Y luego tenemos el fragmento final que también podemos optimizar bastante.
//Obtenemos el inventario UNA SOLA VEZ
$this->data['inventory1'] = $this->inventory_model->getInventoryByID($id);

//Validamos si se encontró el inventario
if (!$this->data['inventory1']) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('inventory_not_found'));
    redirect('inventory');
    exit;
}

//Validamos si el inventario ya fue recibido
if ($this->data['inventory1']->received == 1) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('access_denied_adjustment'));
    redirect('inventory');
    exit;
}

//Si el estatus es 0, actualizamos (con los cambios mencionados)
if ($this->data['inventory1']->cursostatus == 0) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id); //SOLO USAR WHERE EN CASO DE SER NECESARIO
    $this->db->update('inventory', array('cursostatus' => 1));
    $this->data['inventory1'] = $this->inventory_model->getInventoryByID($id); //Recargar datos
}

//Si estado es 1, mandamos el error y redirección
if ($this->data['inventory1']->cursostatus == 1) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('Inventario ocupado favor de esperar a que terminen'));
    redirect('inventory');
    exit;
}

También para el update puedes hacer el uso de transacciones, pero veo que es tan simple que no debería existir problema alguno.

muchas gracias si me funciono.
